# What is the functionality of ZipEntry.setSize in Java?

Tags: java, zip

Is the size information only meant to be used when reading a zip file using Java code? (first figure out the size, then read the file into a buffer whose size >= the recorded size, then transform the bytes into more meaningful structure)

If so, the size cannot be larger or smaller than the real file size. (the file read and transformed by wrong size may be corrupt)

So why not just make the file size recording step automatic? For example, when calling `closeEntry`, let the file size be calculated behind the scenes and the size information be automatically recorded.

I have the same question about `setCrc` and other similar methods. Crc cannot be arbitrarily set, so why not make the crc recording automatic?

Another question is, does the size set by `setSize` affect the  real size of the zip file? For example, if my `zipEntry` only represents a 100 bytes string, but I `setSize(100000)`, then does the zip entry occupy 100000 bytes in the filesystem or 100 bytes?

Comment: It looks like yes, that's what it does.  If you review the [ZipEntry](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.java) and [ZipOutputStream](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.java) sources, you'll find it only sets the size if it's required to over-write that value.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to ever call that method. Consider it internal API used by `ZipInputStream` and co itself.

This is how you write a file to a `ZipOutputStream`:

```
try (var out = new ZipOutputStream(someStream)) {
  out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("myfile.txt"));
  out.write("Hello, World!".getBytes());
  out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file2.txt"));
  out.write("Goodbye!".getBytes());
}
```

This produces a perfectly valid zip file - there is no need to call `.setSize()`, or any `.set` method, on those `ZipEntry` objects. This is perhaps not the best API design (it leads to confusion, and there is effectively zero benefit to being able to pass a `ZipEntry` object to the `putNextEntry` method - that really should have just taken a string or `Path` object instead). But, that's how the API works.

Of course, when you obtain `ZipEntry` objects (because you are using `ZipInputStream` or reading from a `ZipFile` object), CRC, size, and all those other properties just are what they are - set to what the entry in the zip file has. You can call the setters on them if you want to modify the object and then pass it along to some other code. Though, I can't fathom why you would possibly want to do that.

Comment: Have a look at line 194 of [ZipOutputStream](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.java#L194), in regard to _#setSize_.

Answer (score -1):

In response to why there is a *ZipEntry#setSize* method.

The JavaDoc for [ZipOitputStream#putNextEntry](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.java#L194) contains the following *apiNote*.

```java
/**
@apiNote When writing a directory entry, the STORED compression method
should be used and the size and CRC-32 values should be set to 0:

{@snippet lang = "java":
    ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(entryName);
    if (e.isDirectory()) {
        e.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED);
        e.setSize(0);
        e.setCrc(0);
    }
    stream.putNextEntry(e);
}

This allows optimal performance when processing directory entries.
*/
```